# PivotTable VBA format for tabular table and remove subtotals

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I'd like to come up with a way to convert this into variable code to change my PivotTables to 'Tabular' and 'Do Not Show Subtotals' Layout.

This is the code (ommitted some of the field subtotals) that is popping out of the macro box.

```
Sub Macro1()

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").RowAxisLayout xlTabularRow

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields("Field 1").Subtotals = Array _
        (False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields("Field 2").Subtotals = _
        Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
End Sub
```

I've found this previous solution but I don't know how to add in the Tabular part. Also, the code breaks if I have more than one item in 'Values' on the pivottable.

```
Sub PivotTableLayout2b()
Dim PvtTbl As PivotTable
Dim pvtFld As PivotField

Set PvtTbl = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)

'hide Subtotals for all fields in the PivotTable .

With PvtTbl
 For Each pvtFld In .PivotFields
 pvtFld.Subtotals(1) = True
 pvtFld.Subtotals(1) = False
Next pvtFld
End With
End Sub
```